# Regarding the radial motion of photons

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, black-holes, photons, geodesics

Photons move on null geodesics and the equation of motion on equatorial plane after some algebra can be written as

$$e^{\nu}\dot{t}^2-e^{-\nu}\dot{r}^2-r^2\dot{\phi}^2 = 0$$

$\phi =0$  for the radial motion thus above equation becomes

$$e^{\nu}\dot{t}^2-e^{-\nu}\dot{r}^2 = 0$$

from where one can write down

$$\frac{d r}{d t} = \pm \Big(1-\frac{2M}{r}\Big)$$

and integration will lead to

$$t = r +2M\ln\Big|1-\frac{r}{2M}\Big|+C \hspace{12.5mm} \And \hspace{12.5mm} t = -r -2M\ln\Big|1-\frac{r}{2M}\Big|+C$$

Here I'm not sure what kind of physical meaning I should attribute to the final equations. I see at $r=2M$,  $t\to \mp\infty$ but this also confuses my interpretation.

Comment: these are coordinates obtaining by making a bunch of arbitrary choices and famously, coordinates in general relativity have no meaning. Maybe sharpen your question to frame it in a coordinate independent fashion?

Comment: Schwarzschild coordinates have well-defined physical/geometrical meanings. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) explains, “$t$ is the time coordinate (measured by a stationary clock located infinitely far from the massive body), $r$ is the radial coordinate (measured as the circumference, divided by 2π, of a sphere centered around the massive body)”.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks, so above equations define how time is measured by a distant observer as a function of distance? Is this somehow related to gravitational time dilation? (even though I don't see the proper time anywhere). And what happens on the limits $r\to 2M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical meaning is that for a distant observer at fixed $r$, for whom $dt$ approximately represent a proper time interval, ingoing light appears to take an infinitely long time to reach the event horizon.

The other solution is for outgoing light and tells you that light emitted from sources at fixed $r$ takes an increasingly long time to reach a distant observer, with an asymptote to an infinitely long time at the event horizon (where a fixed source cannot exist). This *is* of course the phenomenon of gravitational time dilation.

Comment: So for outgoing light, it's the time it takes for light emitted from a source to be received by a distant observer. And for incoming light, it's the time it takes for light to reach the event horizon from a source?

Answer (score 0):

Those time coordinates represent the incoming and outgoing photons in the spacetime diagram. At the limit $R=2M$, the coordinate time $t\to \infty$ (equivalent to saying it crosses the horizon).